# Edge: how to the put the bookmarks "Imported from Chrome/Bookmarks bar" into Edge bookmark bar (out of the folders)

Tags: bookmarks, import, microsoft-edge

I can import my bookmarks from Chrome to Edge, and then put the folder [Chrome] Bookmarks bar into Edge Bookmark bar, but that's not what I want.

I don't want this:

[image]

But something like this (for the hundred of bookmarks that are in the folder "imported from chrome"):
 [image]

(Edge should do that automatically, but doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved in Edge Chromium (the new edge browser which seems much faster than chrome).

It even convertz specific Chrome's URL (eg. extensions) into  edge URL.